# Butterknife is not working with example

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, butterknife

I saw the Butterknife tutorial and it states:

```
@BindViews({android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2})
TextView textEmail,description;
```

But it isn't working.
And I also tried:

```
@BindViews(android.R.id.text1)
TextView textEmail;

@BindView(android.R.id.text2)
TextView description;
```

But it's not concise!

Comment: It is concise. You can try both ways and it'll work. The android namespace might be confusing at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be binding the android ids rather than your view ids.

Change `android.R.id.text1` to `R.id.yourText`.

To group views, you can group them into list/array:

```
@BindViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

Cheers~

Source: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/